# Replace strings with variable in bash script

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I want to create a bash script to change the configuration file of an application. The script will read a variable and replace the value of a setting that I want to change with the variable value.

```
#!/bin/bash
mysqlurlenv1="jdbc:mysl://xx.xx.xx.xx:3306
mysqlurlenv2="jdbc:mysl://xx.xx.xx.xz:3306
configFile=app.conf
pattern=$1


case "$pattern" in

    1)
            sed -i.bak "s/^\(mysql.db.url =\).*/\1 ${mysqldburl_env1}/" 
            ;;
    2)
            sed -i.bak "s/^\(mysql.db.url =\).*/\1 ${mysqldburl_env2}/"
            ;;
    *)
            echo "Wrong input...try again"

    esac
```

I have a config file with the following entry

```
mysql.db.driver = com.mysql.jdbc.Driver 
mysql.db.url = jdbc:mysql....
mysql.db.uname = admin
```

When I run the script I got this error
sed: -e expression #1, char 40: unknown option to `s'

How to get those defined variable in the config file ? Any help will appreciated

Rgds
Din

Comment: You shouldn't really be using sed with expanded variables like this. The variables you are referencing have / references that are also being used by sed as separators hence sed errors.

Comment: The first two variables are not terminated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using this sed pattern `s/FIND_STRING/REPLACE_STRING`, that is the common way to do it.

But your `REPLACE_STRING` contains `/`, so your pattern will become `s/FIND_STRING/jdbc:mysl://....` and that is invalid, because it contains too much `/`.

Sed accepts any character as field separator, so in your case you need change sed pattern field separator from `/` to something else, like `|`.

Example:

```
$ mysqlurlenv1="jdbc:mysl://xx.xx.xx.xx:3306"
$ echo "mysql.db.url = jdbc:mysql" | sed "s|^\(mysql.db.url =\).*|\1 ${mysqlurlenv1}|"
mysql.db.url = jdbc:mysl://xx.xx.xx.xx:3306
```